# How to display dialog while thread is at sleep in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-alertdialog, thread-sleep

I'm trying to show a progress bar dialog while a loop process is running.

```
fun verifySensor(template: String) {

    //Load progress bar
    managerCallback.startLoading()

    val raw = template.decodeHex().toByteArray()


    var index = 0
    while (index < raw.size) {
        val chunkSize: IntRange = if (index + 19 > raw.lastIndex) {
            IntRange(index, raw.lastIndex)
        } else {
            IntRange(index, index + 19)
        }

        val chunkList = raw.slice(chunkSize)

        val chunk = chunkList.toByteArray()
        Thread.sleep(350)
        index += 20

        writeToService(chunk)
    }
    Thread.sleep(350)
    writeToService("VERIFY".toByteArray())

    //Stop progress bar
    managerCallback.stopLoading()
}
```

I'm calling the abstract class in the activity here::

```
override fun startLoading() {
showLoadingDialog()
}
override fun stopLoading() {
dismissLoadingDialog()
}
```

The methods::

```
private fun createDialog() {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setView(R.layout.layout_loading)
    builder.setCancelable(false)

    dialog = builder.create()
    dialog.window?.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
}

fun showLoadingDialog() {
    dialog.show()
}

fun dismissLoadingDialog() {
    if (dialog.isShowing) dialog.dismiss()
}
```

I'm calling createDialog() in the onCreate of the activity.

I'm expecting the progress bar to show on the main UI thread while the chunk of bytes is sending until it finishes, but it is not showing.

Comment: This isn't necessarily related, but you almost certainly should *not* be using `sleep` here. Tying up threads just to add a delay isn't a good idea; especially if that's running on the application thread. Use a timer or another mechanism.